# How to make child div fluid with respect to parent

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a `two/three` column layout based on screen size.

If window size is greater than `1000` than I need to follow `3 column` layout else I need to follow `two column` layout.

I have achieved this using JS but the code is very messy. Now I want to do it using CSS. But I am stuck.

Here is JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7kuah16h/1/

> Constants:

```
Child Min Width (148px) including padding
child Max Width (196px) including padding
```

If Window Size is `500px` (for eg) Child must be `196px` each and `two column.`

If Window Size is `350px` Child must be `175px` each in `two column`.

If Window size becomes `1000px` then It should convert to 3 column Layout.

In case window size is less than `1000px` all content should be aligned **center**.

Child must change its width a/c to available width.

My Requirements:
[image]

Comment: You have tagged `media queries`, but not using them within your example. It is a way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to [support modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) you can use flex boxes and avoid the use of floating boxes and overflows. Much better for responsive design and mobile.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
    height: 50px;
    flex: 0 1 50%; // 2 boxes 
 }

 @media (min-width: 1000px) {
   .child {
       flex: 0 1 33.33%; // 3 boxes for screens bigger than 1000px 
   }
 }
```

Update your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7kuah16h/9/

Comment: Thnks for replying. 
I have updated your fiddle. I am facing two issues.
1. I want my child div's width to change between 50-100px for eg  based on available size.
2. Only 3 column must be there. Currently it changes to 4-5 based on space. @agapitocandemor

Comment: sorry @Dalvik, could you find a solution to your problem??

Comment: I have found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I've added jsfiddle with a possible solution, but I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Can you confirm this is what you're looking for?

You need to define a media query with width for a specific breakpoint:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .child {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

More details in the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wz5raza3/

Ofcourse, depending on your solution, you need more than this, like paddings, margins or equal column height. For any real-world usage, you would be better off with flexbox.

If you only want to learn basic layouting using older methods, I would suggest: 
http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: @Dalvik Sorry, I've updated the link with the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approximate solution to your problem using `@media screen`. You can adjust the values of the screen and width of your content blocks as required.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  .block {
    width:150px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 351px) {
  .block {
    width:196px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) and (min-width: 501px) {
  .block {
    width:48%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .block {
    width:32%;
  }
}

.container {
  text-align:center;
}

.block {
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#ddd;
  height:175px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add `text-align: center` to the parent div.

Comment: But what about fluid-width of child elements. They are remain fixed. They are not changing based on window size. @chrisstar

Comment: I don't really know what you mean

Comment: center alignment is not the issue. Main issue is child elements are not changing their width a/c to availalbe space.