# Responsive flexbox with 3 items per row, then 2, then 1

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a section which contain six items.

I want 3 items per row on desktop, and on medium device I want 2 items per row, and 1 one Item per on mobile device

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Here is css:

```
.flex-container{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px){
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

This shows me only 3 items on desktop and one per item in mobile, but no 2 items, what do I need to change in my code to get what I want?

Answer (score 7):

The layout can be achieved by adjusting `flex-basis` inside media queries.

Here's the idea:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container > div {
  flex: 1 0 26%;
}

@media ( max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-container > div {
    flex-basis: 34%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 320px) {
  .flex-container > div {
    flex-basis: 51%;
  }
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
.flex-container > div {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L01gup8L/41/)

In the first `flex` rule, `flex-grow` is set to `1`. That means the flex items will consume all free space.

Hence, the width of each item, expressed through `flex-basis`, no longer needs to be the traditional 33.33% (3 items per row), 50% (2 per row) and 100%.

These numbers often have to be manually adjusted (e.g., `calc()`) to make space for margins.

In this case, thanks to flex technology, `flex-grow` consumes remaining space and `flex-basis` needs only to be large enough to enforce a wrap.

So, for example, with `flex-basis: 26%`, only three items can fit on the line. The fourth must wrap. There's plenty of room for margins. `flex-grow` fills up empty space.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing good this way with media queries.. 
Watch out for the 'e' in `.flex-conteiner` should be `.flex-container`

Then use media queries and flex-basis for the rest of screen sizes, for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px){
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 768px){
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
}
```

and for bigger screens use flex basis 33%.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `flex-basis` in the `<div>`,i hope this may help you https://codepen.io/paradian/pen/rZQopv

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are correct, please check my answer in this very similar SO post: [How to make child div fluid with respect to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075299/how-to-make-child-div-fluid-with-respect-to-parent/46080064).

Also I've noted that your media query is wrong, your class is not correct, editing it.